# Program's constant

Tags: windows, command-line

Cmd.exe has the `SET` command that lists the all "%" constants, for example `%USERNAME%` , `%ProgramFiles%` or `%CUSTOMDEFINEDCONSTANT%`. However, after issuing the  `START firefox`  my browser immediately popped up, although neither `firefox` nor `%firefox%` had been mentioned!
 
   Why there are two types of constants? For me, "Program's constant"(that I've rough-and-readily called it)  seems to be redundant so far because START %programName% would be sufficient, doesn't it? I'm also asking about the counterpart of the `SET` command for this strange constants' type.

The question is elementary, but I decided to ask about it here due to the lack of a search coordinates or keywords.

Comment: Those are `Environment Variables`. Also search for `PATH`, that is also an environment variable and explain why you can do `START firefox`.

Comment: @criziot `PATH | FINDSTR firefox` yields no results.

Comment: `PATH` has a list of directories containing binaries. When you try to execute a binary `cmd` will search for it in the directories specified in `PATH`. So `firefox` is not in `PATH`, but the directory containing the `firefox` binary must be. Also you should do `echo $PATH` to see the `PATH`.

Comment: *> Also you should do echo $PATH to see the PATH.*   You’re thinking of PowerShell; the OP is using `cmd` where there is actually a command called `path` that displays or sets the path.

Comment: @Synetech I'm not a Windows user so I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the repair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that, among other things, it looks in this registry key for the executable name:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

This key allows an application to register itself for execution without modifying the PATH variable. [MSDN has more information about application registration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).